# How to search multiple search engines with keywords from own website? Like comparison websites

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm building an app using Meteor.js and React. It incorporates the use of TextRazor's API (NLP) to extract keywords from a body of text. The keywords will then be used to query different websites to bring back results, like how price comparison websites work (although for now I will just incorporate Google and build out the other websites that I want to search within once I've got it working).

How would I go about building the search functionality?

Thanks

Comment: Is your question about how to query google using the keywords you have extracted? Or is it about building some search functionality within meteor/mongo?

Comment: Hi Cenk, sorry I didn't clarify, it's in regards to querying google (or any other searchable website like facebook, youtube etc.) with the keywords extracted.

Comment: Does the answer below help you? If you find it useful, please accept this answer, as it is how this website works.

Answer (score 0):

I think for each external site that you want to search, you have to determine whether it exposes a search API or not. If it does, you would simply have to query via the API, using your local set of keywords, and hope that you don't exceed the API query limits of each site (if you query like that in real time, you might exceed limits at each site).

If the external site does not expose a search API, then you would have crawl it or download it's contents (presuming that you can legally do so... which presumes much), and then you would create a **local index** of the site's content. This means you would need a local search engine platform of some sort (e.g. SOLR, elasticsearch, whatever), and a fairly fat ETL pipeline to transform the website content into the necessary entries or documents in your local index. Then, you would query against your locally built index using your keywords.